# Expected and actual difference

Tags: java

```
Expected :Jos de Verkoper heeft een budget van €60,00 en bezit de volgende games:
Actual   :Jos de Verkoper heeft een budget van €60.00 en bezit de volgende games:
```

Hi stackoverflow,

My Code is good and the test code is also good but only java shows the `Actual` value instead of `Expected` as shown above. What can I do to change it? My Macbook is on US international, maybe that's why?

Comment: Yes, it is probably a locale setting. You can specify the locale when you do formatting. Maybe show a minimal example of what you're doing and somebody can tell you the small bit of code to add.

Comment: thanks, It has something to do with String.format() i need to add a command that it changes to a , i will try it first if it does not work then i will ask you for help

Comment: I need you to edit your post. Instead of including an image, actually write those values in the description. Otherwise, people will downvote your question. There is no need for that. Posting a good question (i.e. no images) should help.

Comment: i got it, ```String s = String.format(Locale.GERMAN,"%s heeft een budget van \u20ac%.2f en bezit de volgende games:", naam, budget);```this was the issue

Comment: only had to add locale.GERMAN

Comment: Still, edit your post with my recommended change. Otherwise, others might come later and downvote your question again.

Comment: on my way to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly why. This has to do how java `Locale` works. In some cases, you have to enforce (override) your system's locale in order for this to work. In your case, for numbers, you might have to do something like this:

```
NumberFormat numFormat = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.GERMAN);// for European separator.
DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat)numFormat;
```

You could also check the system locale like this

```
Locale currentLocale = Locale.getDefault();
```

And perhaps use this condition to execute the change only if the current system locale is not equal to German.

Lastly, you can use the `DecimalFormat` variable to append it's String value to your expected result String.

Comment: ```String s = String.format(Locale.GERMAN,"%s heeft een budget van \u20ac%.2f en bezit de volgende games:", naam, budget);```

Comment: This fixed it, Thanks!

Comment: only had to add locale.GERMAN

Comment: If my post help, I will appreciate it your upvote and making it as the correct answer.

Comment: my account is to noob to upvote ahahaah i can't, if i could then i would but i can't unfortunatly

Comment: like this one  and the following one

Comment: then i have enough points to upvote you

Comment: ah thanks, i upvoted it